# Problem with Mongodb 3.6 version

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6

there is a problem with me 
i cant found the

1. `mongod.exe`
2. `mongo.exe`

In MongoDB 3.6 version, so please help me with an installation of MongoDB properly

there is no any videoes on youtube for how to install 3.6 version of MongoDB.

otherwise please give the link to MongoDB 3.4 version (works properly)...
there is nothing problem with this version...

Can you give me link of mongodb3.4 version....

Comment: Are you asking where you can download it or how to install it? The answer to where you can download it is simply only after you give Mongo your information can you get the free download link. If you're asking how to install Mongo the manual details that process thoroughly https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation

Answer (score 3):

First you download the `Current Stable Release (3.6.0)` from 
[Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit and later, with SSL support x64 with (msi) file](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community)

Once you shall open the https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community , directly it will open to first tab . which is in MongoDB download center, But you have to click on the **Community Server** and download (.msi) files. If you want to install in your windows environment.

**Note:** You can also download (.tgz) and (.zip) files of `MongoDB 3.6.0`. As per requirement you download.

Suppose that i want to install `MongoDB 3.6.0` in my windows environment. So, i shall download the (.msi) files . It is executable file.

**How to install the MongoDB**

Click on the `MongoDB 3.6.0 (.exe)` file,  And click as next button on the other software installation. By default it will install `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin`.

`Note :` If you want to change the installation directory during the installation time , you can select other location other than by default location.

After installation of MongoDB 3.6.0 , create the **C:\data\db** folder in C:\ drive of your system. For properly startup of `mongod` server.

After successfully installation of `MongoDB 3.6.0` , you must check the **BIN** folder. where is `mongod.exe` server and `mongo.exe` shell is exist or not.

For your ref i am attaching the by default location of `MongoDB 3.6.0`.

[image]

If you are able to see `mongod server` and `mongo shell` then open the `command prompt` and go to the installation location of MongoDB Server.

In my place it is **C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin**.

**To start the mongod server for starting the MongoDB services**

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongod
```

and open the second command prompt and go to the location **C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin**

**To start the mongo shell for query**

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongo
```

Hope it will help out to you.